# Are the Steam and Epic Games versions of "The Hunter: Call of the Wild" compatible with each other?

Tags: the-hunter-call-of-the-wild

Yesterday I tried to play The Hunter: Call of the Wild with 2 friends. They have the game on Epic Games and I have the game on Steam. The way we did this was to create a server (friends only) and then invite each other.

We tried every possible way: I created the server, my other 2 friends created the server, but the outcome was always the same: my 2 friends that have the game on Epic Games see each other perfectly in the game, and it all works perfectly for them. As for me: I see the host of the server always as frozen, sometimes it teleports elsewhere, they see me moving but apparently I move super buggy, like moonwalking at the speed of light.

My question here is: is this a known issue? Is this caused by the platform we have the game on (Steam/EG)? Or is it non-related? Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**It is a known issue.**

[**Crossplay works**](https://twitter.com/theHunterCOTW/status/1461786187677323266?s=20&t=7Y5Rj7h8LFz_oOBEANiqWQ), but [apparently](https://www.reddit.com/r/theHunter/comments/r223bq/comment/hm2577f/) only if you and your friends are connected through [Apex Connect](https://apex-connect.avalanchestudios.com/).

But even then, [yes](https://steamcommunity.com/app/518790/discussions/0/3202618375233898432/): succesfully connecting to friends on other platforms is [a roll of dice](https://www.reddit.com/r/theHunter/comments/r31k1y/is_cotw_on_epic_able_to_play_with_people_with_the/). You have to be [lucky](https://www.reddit.com/r/theHunter/comments/r2qlos/epic_games_and_steam_crossplay_issues_in_need_of/), and [patient](https://www.reddit.com/r/theHunter/comments/r3b911/the_hunter_epic_games_and_steam_crossplay/).

Note that most complaints are 9-11 months old, at the moment of writing, and maybe Avalanche has been able to iron out some wrinkles already.